# Smarty assign, calculate 10%

Tags: smarty, prestashop, assign

Need help please!
In prestashop I want to add of value of 10% calculated from `total_to_pay`
Can any one help me to add this ?

```
$this->smarty->assign(array(
            'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($params['total_to_pay'], $params['currencyObj'], false),
            'chequeName' => $this->chequeName,
            'chequeAddress' => Tools::nl2br($this->address),
            'status' => 'ok',
            'id_order' => $params['objOrder']->id
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to a 10%

```
'total_to_pay' => Tools::displayPrice($stats_sales['sales'] * 10 / 100, $params['currencyObj'], false)
```